# Custom Color for TODO and custom TODO differently resharper

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, editor, resharper, todo

I've been trying to find the answer for this and I understand how to change the color of the TODO highlighting. My question is, is there a way for me to make my custom 'todo' which I've labeled as 'DONE' a different color in the editor? (not in the task list- Ctr+Alt+D)

Example:

```
//TODO I need to do something ***RED***

//DONE This was done ***GREEN***
```

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper supports custom todo items, so you can copy an existing one (e.g. the TODO item) and update it to match your text - "DONE". You can give it a custom icon and colour, too, but these are only displayed in the todo items tool window. In the editor, the text is formatted the same as any todo item.

Comment: Right... just wondering if there was a work around for all of the TODO items being formatted the same. It would be nice if resharper could split them out into individual display items.

Comment: So your solution is to buy an expensive package?

Comment: No. My solution is to read the question and respond to the "resharper" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've found a way to do this outside of ReSharper...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166178.aspx

talks about how a VS package can be created to make a new display item   ex NoobyNoobsItems 
Then just go into tools->options->environment->fonts and colors-> and find the NoobyNoobsItems in the 'Display Items' list... But this seems like a lot of work and might still be handled in some way by Resharper.